# Sum with binomial coefficients and integer powers

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, hypergeometric-function

I would like to have an analytic expression for the following sum

$$ G_{n,a} = \sum_{p=1}^n \frac{(-1)^p p^{2(a+n)}}{(n-p)! (n+p)!} \;. $$

I am not sure it has a closed form, but I would at least like to rewrite it having an explicit analytic dependency on the parameters $n,a$ (now $n$ appears as one end of the sum).

I have obtained 
$$ G_{n,a} = \frac{(-1)^n 2^{2a -1}\Gamma(n+a+1/2) Z_a(n)}{\Gamma(n+1/2) \Gamma(a+1)} $$
where $Z_a(n)$ is a polynomial of degree $2a$ in $n$, and for the lowest values in $a$: $Z_0(n) = 1, Z_1(n) = n(n+1)/12$, but I can't get a formula for general $a$.

Answer (score 0):

You may write for first $p^{2(a+n)}$ as a linear combination of the binomial coefficients $\binom{p}{0},\binom{p}{1},\ldots,\binom{p}{2a+2n}$ through [Stirling's numbers of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind). After that,
$$ \sum_{p=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^p}{(n-p)!(n+p)!}\binom{p}{k}=\frac{1}{(2n)!}\sum_{p=0}^{n}\binom{2n}{n-p}\binom{p}{k}(-1)^p$$
can be seen as a convolution: it is $\frac{1}{(2n)!}$ times the coefficient of $x^n$ in the product:
$$\left(\sum_{r\geq 0}\binom{2n}{r}x^r\right)\cdot\left(\sum_{r\geq 0}\binom{r}{k}(-x)^r\right)=(1+x)^{2n}\cdot (-1)^k\frac{x^k}{(1+x)^{k+1}}$$
hence it equals:
$$ \frac{1}{(2n)!}\cdot (-1)^k \binom{2n-k-1}{n-k}=\frac{(-1)^k}{(2n)!}\binom{2n-k-1}{n-1}.$$
From here, it shouldn't be difficult for you to finish.

Your polynomials $Z_a(x)$ should be related with [Stirling's polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_polynomials) in a rather simple way.

Comment: Great!! But do you think the last sum over $k$ can be performed with Stirling's polynomials? I would like to have something meromorphic in $n$, but in this way $n$ appears as one end of the sum over $k$.

Comment: It looks like the final sum can be computed in the "dual" way, i.e. by exploing the identites in the "Generating Functions" paragraph [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).